# Overwriting posts_per_page in new WP_Query

Tags: wp-query

I've tried for hours for a solution to this. Here's the problem, I have a theme that is using `new WP_Query` to set up a loop. That works fine.

I want to take the original query, modify it, and then use another custom query to display the modified list of posts.

It all works fine except for the `'posts_per_page'` parameter, which *appears* to be set correctly (see $args below), but shows all of the posts.

Here is my code:

directory-search.php

```
    <?php
/**
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Parent_Theme
 * @since Parent Theme 1.0
 *
 * Template Name: Directory Search
 */

get_header(); ?>

<section class="content" id="content">

<?php   
$i = 0;

$search_query = get_directory_search_query();

if ( $search_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php                   
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Clickable maps outside contained content area
    // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
?>   
    <div class="bg-map">
        <?php include @ ('includes/include-archive-map.php'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="container header-container">


        <!--    archive header -->
        <header class="page-header entry-header">

            <div class="header-inner">

                <h1 class="page-title">

                    <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ); ?>/assets/css/images/the.png" alt="THE" class="the" />

                    SEARCH RESULTS
                </h1>
                <h2><?php echo $search_query->found_posts; ?> entrie(s) for "<?php 

                    $a = str_replace("-", " ", $a);
                    $t = str_replace("-", " ", $t);
                    switch ('n')
                    {
                    case ( $a !== ''  && $t !== '' && $p !== '' ) :
                        echo $a .', ' . $t .', ' . $p; break;

                    case (  $a !== ''  && $t !== '' ) :
                        echo $a .', ' . $t; break;

                    case ( $a  !== ''  && $p  !== '' ) :
                        echo $a .', ' . $p; break;

                    case ( $t !== '' && $p !== '' ) :
                        echo $t .', ' . $p; break;

                    case ( $a !== '' ) :
                        echo $a; break;

                    case ( $t !== '' ) :
                        echo $t; break;

                    case ( $p !== '' ) :
                        echo $p; break; 

                    default :
                        echo $a .', ' . $t .', ' . $p; break;

                    }
                    ?>"
                </h2>


            <div class="seperator"></div> 
            </div>

        </header>
        <div class="seperator"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="content-bg">

        <div class="container">

            <div class="flexible-row">

                <div class="span8 pull-right">
                    <div class="primary " id="primary" role="main">


                        <?php
                        // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        // Start loop for main archives
                        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ?>

                        <div class="flexible-row featured" id="listings">

                            <?php /* Start the Loop insde content.php so that we can count the numvber of posts */ ?>
                            <?php  ?>

                            <?php
                            global $i;
                            global $deal_count;
                            $deal_count = 0;

                            while ( $search_query->have_posts() ) : $search_query->the_post();
                            $i++;  ?>

                                <?php get_template_part('parts/directory-tile'); ?>
                                <?php if(get_field('deals' ) != 0) $deal_count++; ?>

                            <?php
                            // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                            // End loop for main archives
                            // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                            endwhile; ?>


                            <div class="seperator"></div>
                        </div><?php  // closes flexible row ?>

                        <div class="seperator"></div>
                    </div> <?php // closes primary ?>
                </div>

                <div class="span4 pull-left">
                    <?php get_template_part('parts/board'); ?>
                </div>

            </div><?php  // closes flexible row ?>

            <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>

            <div class="seperator"></div>
        </div> <?php // closes container ?>

<?php 
else : ?>

<div class="bg-map">
        <?php include @ ('includes/include-archive-map.php'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="container header-container">


        <!--    archive header -->
        <header class="page-header entry-header">

            <div class="header-inner">

                <h1 class="page-title">

                    <img src="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ); ?>/assets/css/images/the.png" alt="THE" class="the" />

                    SEARCH RESULTS
                </h1>
                <h2>No Results</h2>


            <div class="seperator"></div> 
            </div>

        </header>
    <div class="seperator"></div> 
    </div>

    <div class="content-bg">

        <div class="container">                

            <div class="primary" id="primary" role="main">       

                <div class="flexible-row featured" id="listings">


                    <article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found padding-trbl">

                        <h2><?php _e( 'Sorry, nothing was found', 'parentheme' ); ?></h2>


                        <div class="entry-content">
                            <p>No results were found for the search: <strong><?php

                            if ( $a ) :
                                $a = str_replace("+", " ", $a);
                                echo $a .' '; endif;
                            if ( $t ) :
                                $t = str_replace("-", " ", $t);
                                echo $t .' '; endif;
                            if ( $p ) :
                                echo $p; endif;
                        ?></strong>. Maybe broadening your search will help?</p>

                        </div><!-- .entry-content -->

                    </article><!-- #post-0 -->

                    <div class="seperator"></div>
                </div><?php  // closes flexible row ?>



                <div class="seperator"></div>
            </div> <?php // closes primary ?>

            <?php //get_sidebar(); ?>


            <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>

            <div class="seperator"></div>
        </div> <?php // closes container ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    </div><?php // closes content-bg ?>

</section><?php // ends #content ?>    
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

custom-queries.php

```
<?php

function get_directory_search_query($s='', $t='', $a='', $p='') {

    if(empty($s)) $s = $_GET['s'];
    if(empty($a)) $a = $_GET['a'];
    if(empty($t)) $t = $_GET['t'];
    if(empty($p)) $p = $_GET['p'];

    if ( $a  ) :
        $search_args = array(
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'area-2',
                    'value' => $a,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
            )
        );
    endif;


    if ( $t  ) :
        $search_args = array(
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'types',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $t
                )
            )
        );
    endif;


    if ( $p  ) :
        $search_args = array(
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'price',
                    'value' => $p,
                    'compare' => '='
                )
            )
        );
    endif;


    if ( $a  && $t ) :
        $search_args = array(
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'area-2',
                    'value' => $a,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
            ),
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'types',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $t
                )
            )
        );
    endif;

    if ( $a  && $p ) :
        $search_args = array(
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key' => 'area-2',
                    'value' => $a,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'price',
                    'value' => $p,
                    'compare' => '='
                )
            )

        );
    endif;

    if ( $p  && $t ) :
        $search_args = array(
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'price',
                    'value' => $p,
                    'compare' => '='
                )
            ),
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'types',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $t
                )
            )
        );
    endif;

    if ( $a  && $p && $t ) :
        $search_args = array(
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key' => 'area-2',
                    'value' => $a,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'price',
                    'value' => $p,
                    'compare' => '='
                )
            ),
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'types',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $t
                )
            )
        );

    endif;

    $search_args['post_type'] = 'directory';
    $search_args['posts_per_page'] = -1;
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $search_args['paged'] = $paged;

    $search_query = new WP_Query( $search_args );

    return $search_query;
}
```

board.php

```
<?php

global $search_query;
global $deal_count;
$args = array_merge(
    $search_query->query_vars,
    array(
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'orderby' => 'rand'
    )
);

$args['meta_query'][] = array(
    'key'     => 'deals',
    'value'   => '0',
    'compare' => '!='
);

$args['post_type'] = 'directory';

$board_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

<?php if( $board_query->have_posts()): ?>
    <div class="board">

        <h1 class="board__title">The Board</h1>

            <div class="board__content">

                <?php while($board_query->have_posts()): $board_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <?php get_template_part('parts/offer'); ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>

            </div>

        <?php if($deal_count > 3) { ?>
            <?php
            $get_data = '';
            $data_vars = array('s', 'a', 't', 'p');
            foreach($data_vars as $data_var){
                if(!empty($_GET[$data_var])) $get_data .= 'data-'.$data_var.'="'.$_GET[$data_var].'" ';
            }
            ?>
            <button class="board__refresh" <?php echo $get_data; ?>>Refresh Board</button>
        <?php } ?>

    </div>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This is the `$args` array that get's passed to `new WP_Query($args)`:

```
Array
(
[meta_query] => Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[key] => area-2
[value] => Bank
[compare] => LIKE
)

[1] => Array
(
[key] => deals
[value] => 0
[compare] => !=
)

)

[posts_per_page] => 3
[paged] => 1
[post_type] => directory
[error] =>
[m] =>
[p] => 0
[post_parent] =>
[subpost] =>
[subpost_id] =>
[attachment] =>
[attachment_id] => 0
[name] =>
[static] =>
[pagename] =>
[page_id] => 0
[second] =>
[minute] =>
[hour] =>
[day] => 0
[monthnum] => 0
[year] => 0
[w] => 0
[category_name] =>
[tag] =>
[cat] =>
[tag_id] =>
[author] =>
[author_name] =>
[feed] =>
[tb] =>
[comments_popup] =>
[meta_key] =>
[meta_value] =>
[preview] =>
[s] =>
[sentence] =>
[fields] =>
[menu_order] =>
[category__in] => Array
(
)

[category__not_in] => Array
(
)

[category__and] => Array
(
)

[post__in] => Array
(
)

[post__not_in] => Array
(
)

[tag__in] => Array
(
)

[tag__not_in] => Array
(
)

[tag__and] => Array
(
)

[tag_slug__in] => Array
(
)

[tag_slug__and] => Array
(
)

[post_parent__in] => Array
(
)

[post_parent__not_in] => Array
(
)

[author__in] => Array
(
)

[author__not_in] => Array
(
)

[ignore_sticky_posts] =>
[suppress_filters] =>
[cache_results] => 1
[update_post_term_cache] => 1
[update_post_meta_cache] => 1
[nopaging] => 1
[comments_per_page] => 50
[no_found_rows] =>
[order] => DESC
[orderby] => rand
)
```

## What I've tried

Everything I can think of. I've tried setting the `'posts_per_page'` parameter every way I could. I've tried using `'showposts'`, `'posts_per_archive_page'`, and `'nopaging'`.

I just don't understand how a new query, with the correctly set parameters, behaves like this.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the dump of your `$args` above, `nopaging` is set to `1` which disables pagination (equivalent to `posts_per_page = -1`).

Try setting this to `false` and see if it fixes your issue. You can then look into why it's being set.